# Git stash created strange branch

Tags: git, version-control, branch

i'm new to theese semi-advanced concepts about git.
I was working on branch "mobile_perwanger" and wanted to switch back to "main" without committing the changes; so i stashed them to later restore.

When i pushed to origin it created this, i think, strange branch that i don't know what it is.

I don't have much more infos on how to replicate since this operation was done in a hurry.

Everything was done through an IDE (servoy, which runs eclipse beneath)

Is it possible to "delete" that branch?

(By hovering the commit on vscode it sas that the commit is included in HEAD)

[image]

Comment: From your screenshot, everything looks ok. What is the "strange branch" you are talking about? Also, stashing will have no impact on your branches.

Comment: You already had branches `main` and `mobile_perwanger`. Your screenshot also has the branch `svilluppi`. Since you don’t mention what “this strange branch” is, I am left to assume that `svilluppi` is the branch in question. If so I don’t see how that could have happened given the steps that you described.

Comment: You are probably confused by "main" not being on top of the list. This is likely due to the fact that the list is sorted by the commit timestamp and the commit on the branch "mobile_perwanger" is newer than the commit on "main" is. However, since the "main" branch is printed in bold it indicates that this is the branch you are currently working on.